# Total memory used by Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, memory, heap-memory

I have read this article **Find out your Java heap memory size**
http://www.mkyong.com/java/find-out-your-java-heap-memory-size/ is helpful for me to understand the memory used by Tomcat.

According to the above article, the total memory is:

heap + perm + stack (threads)

I have the following questions:

1. If we set a max on the heap and perm, am I right that the total memory used by Tomcat depends on the number of threads?
2. Each thread uses both stack memory for itself and heap memory (because it creates objects)?
3. The more memory a machine has, the more threads Tomcat can serve, up to the point where either heap or the server runs out of available memory? At that point, JVM throws the OutOfMemory execption?

Comment: That's a very simplified view, not taking into account class and other sorts of native allocations. The answer will depend on whether you plan to use Java8 - do you?

Comment: @mabi, where do "class and other sorts of native allocations" get memory from? From heap? I use Java 8 on Windows Server 2012R2 with 128GB memory. Thanks for chiming in!